# implement a mobile action search bar in flex 4.11 like ios

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6

I am building an mobile app and I need to create a search bar something like the iOS search bar. 
Is this possible using flex 4.11 from Apache ?[image]

Comment: if you're asking whether there is an existing component that does this, then the answer is no. Can it be created in Flex? yes. googling should provide some examples

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/People-in-action/eskimo think there's one in there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Flex `ActionBar` component that you have access to primarily when using `ViewNavigator`-based apps. There isn't a pre-built way to run searches or even a search component, though. You would have to build a custom `ActionBar` and skin for that ActionBar which would duplicate the functionality. You would also have to create a `View` which displays the results and a controller for actually running the search.